# how can i solve a problem in recursion using c language?

Tags: recursion

There is a series, , where the next term is the sum of pervious three terms. Given the first three terms of the series, , , and  respectively, you have to output the nth term of the series using recursion.

Recursive method for calculating nth term is given below.

Answer (score 0):

*No code in post == no code in answer!*

**Fast iterative approach**
You need to start off with thee additional parameters that have the 3 initial values for 0, 1, and 2. You then return the first if the n (first parameter)  is zero. Otherwise you recurse by reducing n by 1, use your 2nd and 3rd initial value as 1st and 2nd, then compute the new third by adding the three initial values you had in thir round. If you are required to have a function with only one parameter you make eiher use of default values or make two functions, one with the one requireed parameter that just calls the recursive implementation with the 3 additional init values.

**Slow recursive approach**
You have a base case that returns teh initial values for 0, 1, and 2. Then add a default case that returns the 3 recursions.

As a hint: Look for Fibonacci solutions here. It is the exact same algorithm only it uses the two last instead of three. The solutions would be adaptable for 3.

Comment: Node in post == _don't_ answer.